# how can i have multiple barplots together in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a problem with having barplot of my data. I consider a data sample like this:

```
data <- data.frame(P=sample(c("A","B","C","D") , 10,replace = TRUE) ,O=c(2009,1299,4876,3258,1324,3609,2176,4076,2314,6590), X=c(4754,9800,7600,1760,2840,3710,3708,9126,7777,8220))
data <- data %>%
  group_by(P) %>%
  summarize(mean_O=mean(O),mean_X=mean(X))
```

Now I want to have a barplot which x.axis represents P variable and in y.axis have both the mean_O and mean_X values. In other words, I want to have mean_X and mean_O for each type of P variable both together in one graph.

How can I have this plot with `ggplot()+geom_bar`?

Any little help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the output from `dput(data1)` in you question.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Olivia,Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
# read your data
d <- read.table(text="insurerType     x1      x2      x3
 a              12      14       15
 b              10      15       10
 c               7      23        0", header=T)

# load ggplot2 and dplyr within 
library(tidyverse)
# transform the data using dplyr and tidyr and plot the bars using fill to
# get the three bars per insurer. I used geom_col as it uses stat_identity as default  
d %>%
  gather(key, value, -insurerType) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=insurerType, y=value, fill = key)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

```
# Another solution would be to use a facet like this:
d %>%
  gather(key, value, -insurerType) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=key, y=value, fill=key)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    facet_wrap(~insurerType)
```

[image]

Comment: ,Thanks alot,That's exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

Reshape the data first

`library(reshape2)`

```
df2 = melt(df)
```

Then Plot

`library(ggplot2)`

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=insurerType, y=value, fill=variable)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
     theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: 'geom_bar(stat="identity"' has been subsumed by `geom_col`. If you check `?geom_bar` it says `If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use geom_col instead`

Comment: `geom_col( color="black", position=position_dodge())` gives the same result